# Outputting context (-C) for grep produces massive files

Tags: text-processing, grep, osx, output

**Task:**

I'm using `grep` to search some text files, piping the results from one `grep` (excluding some lines) to another (matching some lines) + displaying some context using the `-C` parameter as shown below:

```
grep -v "Chapter" *.txt | grep -nE  -C1 " leaves? "
```

**Problem:**

This works very well when printing the results, but produces very large files (~ several GB) and takes forever when I write it to file like so:

```
grep -v "Chapter" *.txt | grep -nE  -C1 " leaves? " > out.txt
```

**Troubleshoot:**

1. The `grep` returns only 1345 lines (according to `wc`), printout takes a few seconds
2. The output in the large output files looks legit, aka actual results from input files.
3. Replacing the `-C` operator with `-A` or `-B` produces good output files in the KB size.

**Questions:**

- Why is this happening?
- Is there something about the `-C` that breaks things this way?
- Or is there a different issue I am overlooking?

Any hints appreciated! Running this in the MacOS terminal. I was following [this](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) man.

Comment: *"Or is there a different issue I am overlooking?"* well, you are writing to file `out.txt` while also reading from any files matching `*.txt`, maybe that results in a kind of race condition?

Comment: @steeldriver that is a very good point that I have not considered. I don't know why -A and -B would work under these circumstances then but I'll give it a shot as soon as I am back on that machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the directory where you're writing `out.txt`. For example change this command to this:

```
$ grep -v "Chapter" *.txt | grep -nE  -C1 " leaves? " > /tmp/out.txt
```

#### Example

Here you can see what's happening when you enable verbose output in your Bash shell.

```
$ set -x
$ grep -v "Chapter" *.txt | grep -nE  -C1 " leaves? " > out.txt
+ grep --color=auto -nE -C1 ' leaves? '
+ grep --color=auto -v Chapter file01.txt file02.txt file03.txt file04.txt file05.txt file06.txt file07.txt file08.txt file09.txt file10.txt out.txt
```

Notice that it's taking the argument `*.txt` and expanding it, and it includes the the file `out.txt`. So you're literally parsing this file as you write out to it.

#### Why?

If you think about what a shell does when output from 1 command is piped into the next it makes sense. The shell parses the commands you just gave it, looking for pipes (`|`). When it encounters them it has to run the ones from the right in order to set up the redirection of STDIN/STDOUT between the commands occuring within the pipes.

You can use the `sleep` command to see how the shell parses things as more pipes are added:

```
$ sleep 0.1 | sleep 0.2 | sleep 0.3 | sleep 0.4
+ sleep 0.2
+ sleep 0.3
+ sleep 0.4
+ sleep 0.1

$ sleep 0.1 | sleep 0.2 | sleep 0.3 | sleep 0.4 | sleep 0.5
+ sleep 0.2
+ sleep 0.3
+ sleep 0.4
+ sleep 0.5
+ sleep 0.1
```

Doing this with `echo` + writing to a file also shows the order via the file accesses & the `stat` command:

```
$ echo "1" > file1 | echo "2" > file2 | echo "3" > file3 | echo "4" > file4
+ echo 2
+ echo 3
+ echo 4
+ echo 1

$ stat file* | grep -E "File|Access: [[:digit:]]+"
+ grep --color=auto -E 'File|Access: [[:digit:]]+'
+ stat file1 file2 file3 file4
  File: ‘file1’
Access: 2018-08-11 23:55:20.868220474 -0400
  File: ‘file2’
Access: 2018-08-11 23:55:20.865220576 -0400
  File: ‘file3’
Access: 2018-08-11 23:55:20.866220542 -0400
  File: ‘file4’
Access: 2018-08-11 23:55:20.867220508 -0400
```

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed answer. I changed the file location / name and it works no prob. I still don't understand why I would not run into this problem when doing `-A` or `-B` but I see the error of my thinking: since the file output is the right-most command, in my mind this happened "after everything else"...